# Cleanup partly-uploaded files handled by TemporaryFileUploadHandler in Django

Tags: django, django-forms

I am using the TemporaryFileUploadHandler to upload files. If a user is uploading a large file and cancels the upload, the file remains in my temporary directory.

Is there a way to trap a cancelled upload (connection reset before a file was fully uploaded) in order to cleanup these files?

The only alternative I can think of is a cron job which looks at the temp directory and deletes files which have not been updates in some reasonable amount of time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if it helps, but you may try to connect to django request signals:

request_finished - Sent when Django finishes processing an HTTP request.

got_request_exception - This signal is sent whenever Django encounters an exception while processing an incoming HTTP request.

I think Django should raise error if connection is aborted, so the usage of second one is probably a solution. Please let me know it it helps.