# Django save image temporarily for user process in template

Tags: python, django

I figure the title is somewhat confusing but that's the best I came up with.

I have an upload image form which I want to process the image file further after the user upload it (with the user - cropping using jquery) rather than put it on the model `imagefield` right away.

Meaning, I need to save the image temporarily so I can present it to the user in a template with the jquery crop plugin.

My current solution is ugly, I made a model called `TempImageToProcess` which I save the image to and from that I re-present it to the user to further process.

So my question is: is there any elegant way to save image temporarily in Django?

Answer (score 3):

You should check `TemporaryFileUploadHandler` in this [section](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/file-uploads/?from=olddocs#upload-handlers).

Look [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8670982/cleanup-partly-uploaded-files-handled-by-temporaryfileuploadhandler-in-django) `SO` question for a clean up afterwards if any unexpected error occur or validation errors.

Hope this will lead you some where.